# Binding DGV to datatable created on other thread. UI thread is taking control away from datatable thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview, datatable, delegates

The Problem:

I am trying to have a DataGridView show data that is from a DataTable created and managed by another thread. This thread raises an event to notify the UI thread to update the DGV.

When I try to update it with the UI thread, the UI thread takes ownership of the DataTable, so then when the other thread tries to add another entry I get a cross-thread operations error.

I've been reading up on delegates and how to accomplish this but the problem is that since I want to bind an object from one thread to another, no matter which thread access' the UpdateTable sub, its working with an 1 object it doesn't own.

...

Things I have tried:

I've tried using delegates, however I am new to multithreading apps so I'm struggling to understand what I am doing, I've been making tons of small changes and seeing what happens when I step through debugging.

I've tried to create copies of the data with the UI thread and then bind the DGV to that, but accessing the data in any way from the UI thread locks out the other thread.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I've been googling and digging through forums for a day now and have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I went the copying data route. When I originally tried I was doing

```
NewDataTable = OldDataTable
```

Where NewDataTable is controlled by the UI thread and bound to the DataGridView and OldDataTable is managed by a different thread. This was not actually creating a copy, it was pointing to the old table.

So I did

```
NewDataTable = OldDataTable.copy()
```

This solved it. It's not ideal because if the table starts getting large it may suck up time and memory but for my application it will work. I wish I could figure out a more elegant way to do it, but so-be-it.